# How to find duplicates in a string using Spark SQL?

Tags: mysql, dataframe, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I want to find duplicates in a string, I wonder is there any way that we can find this using spark sql. Below is the query which i've written.

```
spark.sql("""select case when lower(value) like '%,code,%' or lower(value) like '%,code%' or lower(value) like '%code,%' then 'Y' else 'N' end as value from input""").show(false)
```

Input :

```
val sample = Seq(("code,code")).toDF("value")
```

The issue is what if the value 'code' repeats twice? in that case my requirement is to return flag 'N'. Is there any way to do that using Spark SQL? Please share your suggestions. TIA

Comment: ''code' repeats twice' - exactly twice or more than once what if 2 or more what if none?

Comment: yes, if more than twice then should return 'N', if none then also should return 'N'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can establish the number of occurances using length and replace

```
set @a = 'code,aaa';
set @b = 'code,code';
set @c = 'aaa,bbb,ccc';

select @a, length(@a) - length(replace(@a,'code','')) lengthdiff,
        case when length(@a) - length(replace(@a,'code','')) = 4 then 'y'
             when length(@a) - length(replace(@a,'code','')) >= 4 then 'n'
        else 'n'
        end  occurances
;

+----------+------------+------------+
| @a       | lengthdiff | occurances |
+----------+------------+------------+
| code,aaa |          4 | y          |
+----------+------------+------------+
1 row in set (0.001 sec)

select @b, length(@b) - length(replace(@b,'code','')) lengthdiff,
        case when length(@b) - length(replace(@b,'code','')) = 4 then 'y'
             when length(@b) - length(replace(@b,'code','')) > 4 then 'n'
        else 'n'
        end  occurances
;

+-----------+------------+------------+
| @b        | lengthdiff | occurances |
+-----------+------------+------------+
| code,code |          8 | n          |
+-----------+------------+------------+
1 row in set (0.000 sec)

select @c, length(@c) - length(replace(@c,'code','')) lengthdiff,
        case when length(@c) - length(replace(@c,'code','')) = 4 then 'y'
             when length(@c) - length(replace(@c,'code','')) > 4 then 'n'
        else 'n'
        end  occurances
;

+-------------+------------+------------+
| @c          | lengthdiff | occurances |
+-------------+------------+------------+
| aaa,bbb,ccc |          0 | n          |
+-------------+------------+------------+
1 row in set (0.001 sec)
```

Comment: Hi @P.Salmon could you please suggest on how to validate if the input is code1 or 1code. In this case it should print 'N' as it has 1 next to code or when it is before code. please suggest me some ideas

Comment: Code still works as far as I can recall - did you try it?

Comment: yes it is working absolutely fine, but the think is if i the input is code1 it is printing 'Y' it should give 'N'... as the expected value is only 'code'

Comment: If you are looking for an exact match on tokens this solution isn't..you should search for mysql split string and include logic in a procedure or function.